# Insert JSON data from files in postgresql table with multiple JSON fields

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, psql

I have a table T in PostgreSQL DB with following schema

```
(
 id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
 meta JSON,
 data JSON
)
```

I want to ingest JSON data into meta and data fields from two files, `meta.json` and `data.json`. How can I do this using `psql` or `pgcli`?

Comment: So you want to insert the entire contents of meta.json into the `meta` column (and similiarly for data.json) resulting in a single row being inserted?

Comment: [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) is the standard sql function for importing data from files. It works for any kind of data type including json and jsonb.